# Position of ItemClick event on a ListView Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have a `ListView` which shows the products in a shopping cart. The `datatemplate` defines an **increment** and a **decrement** amount button for each product.

If the user wants to tap one of these buttons, there's a chance that they tap next to the button, so the `ItemClick` event will be triggered. I want to disable `ItemClick` in the area of the button. I had an idea to get the position where the `ItemClick` event occurred, and determine if it's in the disabled area which I defined.

Is it possible? Any other idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a simple way to do this. Use an element as the "disabled area" around these increment/decrement buttons. In the `ItemClick` handler, say `if (e.OriginalSource == **the element which is the disabled area**) return;`.

This works, because the `ItemClickedEventArgs` is a `RoutedEventArgs` which always contains the element where it originated from. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemclickeventargs

Comment: Thank you! It's indeed a really simple, elegant solution!

Comment: e.OriginalSource is always ListView for me, how did you get the "disabledArea" ?

Answer (score 2):

Why doing it the hard way?

You can change the `DataTemplate` in a way that each `ListViewItem` gets divided into two parts, *"change amount part"* and *"item's info part"* :

```
    <ListView ItemClick="OnItemClick">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <!-- This is the item's info part -->
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" >
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Qnty}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <!-- This is the change amount part -->
                                <StackPanel Tag="Oops!" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" >
                                    <Button Content="▲" />
                                    <Button Content="▼" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

Now you can try one of the following ways to handle `ItemClick` properly:

**First solution:** You can find out what was the [OriginalSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.routedeventargs.originalsource) that raised the `ItemClick` event. if it was the *"change amount part"*, then user probably tapped it by mistake and the event should be cancelled, if it was *"item's info part"* then the event should be raised:

```
    private void OnItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var tag = ((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).Tag;

        if (tag != null && tag.ToString() == "Oops!")
        {
            return;
        }
        //else: do whatever needs to be done on item click
    }
```

**Second solution:**
You can set the `ListView` to `SelectionMode="None"` and `IsItemClickEnabled="False"`, and then I added Tapped handlers for each element manually (e.g. `ItemTapped` for item's info part and `OnIncreaseTapped` and `OnDecreaseTapped` for the buttons):

```
    <ListView ItemClick="OnItemClick" SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="False">
         ...
                                <!-- This is the item's info part -->
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Tapped = "OnItemTapped" Grid.Column="0" >
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Qnty}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <!-- This is the change amount part -->
                                <StackPanel Tag="Oops!" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" >
                                    <Button Content="▲" Tapped = "OnIncreaseTapped"/>
                                    <Button Content="▼" Tapped = "OnDecreaseTapped"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
```

**Third solution:**
Why even let user to tap the wrong area? I'd rather get rid of this area by using an `ItemTemplate` like this:

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion 1**
You might be able to listen to `ManipulationStarted` root of the `DataTemplate` and check the `e.Position` in the event handler if the input was near the buttons. If it's too close set a `bool` like `IsCloseToStepperButtons` to true and check for that bool in the `ItemClick` event handler.

Haven't tested this, but I think the events are fired in the desired order.

**Suggestion 2**
You could skip the whole `ItemClick` event and add an event listener to the other part of the `DataTemplate`. Put a margin between the two parts to prevent accidental clicks.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. The ManipulationStarted event is not firing.